# Magento 2 bespoke category page.

Tags: magento2, category

Is it possible to create a bespoke category page with only select filter options that won't affect other category pages?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a CMS page containing a 'Catalog Products List' widget. This widget allows you to specify a set of conditions with which to generate a grid of applicable products.